# $\frac6{10+x^2+y^2}+\frac6{10+y^2+z^2}+\frac6{10+x^2+z^2}\ge \frac{(\sqrt6+\sqrt6+\sqrt6)^2}{30+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to get to that on the right side?
$$\frac6{10+x^2+y^2}+\frac6{10+y^2+z^2}+\frac6{10+x^2+z^2}\ge
\frac{(\sqrt6+\sqrt6+\sqrt6)^2}{30+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$

We also have $x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 12$, if it's relevant.
I tried using AM-GM and AM-HM, but I can't get to that on the right side.

Comment: Do you really mean for the three terms on the left to be identical?

Comment: It' a cyclic sum probably.

Comment: Oh. I edited it now. Sorry.

Comment: Engel's form of Cauchy Schwarz = [Titu's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/)

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$AM\ge HM$

$\displaystyle \frac{(10+x^2+y^2)+(10+y^2+z^2)+(10+z^2+x^2)}3\ge\frac3{\frac1{10+x^2+y^2}+\frac1{10+y^2+z^2}+\frac1{10+z^2+x^2}}$

$\displaystyle\frac1{10+x^2+y^2}+\frac1{10+y^2+z^2}+\frac1{10+z^2+x^2}\ge\frac9{30+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$

Multiply both sides by $6$ and you have your solution.

$[(\sqrt6+\sqrt6+\sqrt6)^2=54]$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(t)=6/(10+t)$ is convex in $[0,+\infty)$. Hence, by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),
$$f(x^2+y^2)+f(x^2+z^2)+f(z^2+y^2)\geq
3f\left(\frac{2x^2+2y^2+2z^2}{3}\right).$$
Now
$$3f\left(\frac{2x^2+2y^2+2z^2}{3}\right)=
\frac{3\cdot 6}{10+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)/3}\\=
\frac{3^2\cdot 6}{30+2(x^2+y^2+z^2)}$$
which is exactly your RHS.

Comment: ...which is Jensen.

Comment: Yes, by Jensen's inequality.